# Pyspark - cache and union

Tags: python, pyspark

I am running a code like this:

```
def cache_and_union(df1, df2):
   df1.cache()

   df = df1.union(df2)

   return df.collect()
```

For some reason, when performing the collect method the cache is not performed and used (does not appear in stages neither storage). Why could this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this code example, you're not actually using `cache` in any way. `cache` suggests Spark that df1 would be used multiple times, so it should be cached, and not be recomputed each time. In your code sample, you're just joining df1 and doing a collect.